# javascript regexp заменить текст до определенного символа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка вида `00001000`.

Нужно написать регулярку, заменяющую все нули слева от `1` на `2`.

Количество нулей может быть разным.

Примеры преобразований:

- `00001000` -> `22221000`;
- `0010000` -> `2210000`.

Comment: Для тех, кто задаёт вопросы и тех, кто делает правки - будьте внимательны! От этого зависит скорость и качество ответов. Вот, что это: "... а для 0010000 - 22210000."? Почему из 7 знаков получилось 8 ? Уточните.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Заменяем нули перед каждой из единиц:**

Если единиц может быть несколько и требуется заменять нули перед каждой из них, то решение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
var original = "00001000100101100";
var result = original.replace(/0(?=0*1)/g, "2");
console.log(result);
```

***Примечание***: данный вариант базируется на использовании `non-capturing group` `via zero-width positive lookahead`.

---

**Заменяем нули только перед первой из единиц:**

Если, все же, единиц может быть несколько и нужно заменить нули только перед первой из них, то этого можно достичь следующим образом:

```js
var original = "00001000100101100";
var result = original.replace(/(?<=^0*)0(?=0*1)/g, "2");
console.log(result);
```

***Примечание***: данное решение базируется на `non-capturing group` `via zero-width positive lookbehind` & `via zero-width positive lookahead`.

---

**Заменяем нули только перед первой из единиц (альтернатива):**

В соответствии с предложением из комментариев, оказывается, в JS за счет специфичного флага [sticky](https://github.com/mjavascript/practical-modern-javascript/blob/master/ch07.asciidoc#sticky-matching-flag-y) можно достигнуть аналогичного для данной ситуации результата куда проще:

```js
var original = "00001000100101100";
var result = original.replace(/0(?=0*1)/gy, '2');
console.log(result);
```

---

**Примечания**:

- любое из вышепредставленных решений является корректным для случая, когда единица может быть всего одна, но меня интересовали более сложные случаи;
- любое из вышепредставленных решений можно было бы оптимизировать использовав `reluctant` вместо `greedy quantifiers` (заменив все `*`/`+` на `*?`/`+?`), но это лишь усложнило бы примеры, при этом не принеся никакого прироста производительности вследствие используемых при поиске символов (прирост был бы ощутим в случае использования потенциально перекрывающих друг друга групп символов).

Comment: Если потребуется больше пояснений к используемым регуляркам, то просьба подсказать где именно :)

Comment: В JS есть еще один интересный флаг [sticky](https://github.com/mjavascript/practical-modern-javascript/blob/master/ch07.asciidoc#sticky-matching-flag-y).
Если задача заменить только первые нули, то вариант с просмотрами назад и вперед [сокращается до такого](https://regex101.com/r/Ow4ins/1) `'00100100'.replace(/0(?=0*1)/gy, '2')` => `'22100100'`

Comment: Ухты, даже не знал, что в JS имеется такой флаг, теперь буду знать, спасибо :)

В ту же [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) такого не завезли, видимо в JS регулярки более востребованы, раз такой появился.